# Complex stateful logic in MVVM architecture

Tags: architecture, mobile, mvvm, layers, state

I'm building a mobile app in Flutter, and the project has several distinct layers. The top part is something better described as MVVM: dumb View layer that performs rendering and delegates actions to reactive stateful ViewModel. The ViewModel itself is kept rather lean too, with all the actual logic pushed down to Model (services, entities, repositories, etc). The services have been stateless by now, with all the inputs and outputs going through the method parameters, in this way they are easy to test.

Now I have a task that involves some complex stateful logic: when the user invokes an action, I need to add a job to a queue and then gradually process the jobs in the background one by one over a period of time. I also need to constantly report the progress back to the user. Imagine some sophisticated download manager or a similar app. I'm in doubt on how to organize the code in this case:

1. Can the service be stateful? What are the benefits/drawbacks? In all the classic books services, use cases, etc are usually kept stateless
2. If the service is stateless, then where do I put the state of the job queue?
3. If the queue is to be put to the service, then how do I make it reactive to provide the constant immediate feedback on each step?
4. Should I apply to the service the same reactive framework that I use for the VM?
5. How do I make the complex, stateful service communicate with the VM and report its state reactively?
6. How do I test the whole thing, if the logic is now stateful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The job queue should be part of the model, since the model represents the application state, and "jobs to do" is part of the application state.

Then all the other questions pretty much solve themselves. There's a background job executor service that references the queue and executes the jobs. Whenever a job is done, it updates the queue accordingly. The queue has status update events that the VM can hook into: job starting, job finished. If you need finer-grained feedback, the job itself has progress update events as well, which the VM subscribes to when a job is started and unsubscribes from when the job is finished.

Comment: If we zoom a bit more on the model part here, where does this state belong to? It must not be a "service" I guess, because those are usually stateless. What kind of component can keep this temporary, reactive state? Is it a kind of "reactive repository" or what?

Comment: I'd say it's a top-level part of your application model.